# Power Apps set(var for DateAdd is blank

Tags: powerapps, dateadd

I am new to PowerApps and am trying to follow a Calendar build.   I am trying to set a variable for a date that populates the first Sunday of the month.

Set (varVideoMonth, DateValue(Month (Today()) & "/" & "'¡" & "/" & Year (Today())));
Set (varVideoFirstDayView, DateAdd(varfirstDayMonth, - Weekday(varVideoMonth), Days));

This is the code that returns varVideoFirstDayView = Blank.

the other (varVideoMonth) returns the date properly.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.   Any suggestions would be helpful.   Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `varfirstDayMonth`? What is `'¡` in your formula, is it supposed to be `01` first of the current month?